# Finding a Hilbert space from a given group

Tags: representation-theory, hilbert-spaces

Suppose we are given a group $G$. Is there a method to find out that $G$ is the unitary group of a Hilbert space $H$ or not?! And if yes, what about a way to find this Hilbert space?!